# Valor do campo relacionado a outro campo de outra tabela?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, microsoft-access, tabela-html

No MS Access tenho duas tabelas: **tbCursos** e **tbPessoas**
tbPessoas contém: `ID`, `Nome`, `CursoID`, `CursoNome`;
tbCursos contém: `ID`, `Nome`;

É possível fazer o campo `CursoNome` da tabela **tbPessoas** ter o mesmo valor do nome do curso da outra tabela de acordo com o valor do `CursoID`?

**tbPessoas**:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**tbCursos**:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nas duas imagens acima, `CursoNome` tem como valor 'Direito' pois o valor de `CursoID` é 2.

A questão é, como fazer para que ao mudar o valor do campo `CursoID`, o campo `CursoNome` mude conforme o conteúdo da outra tabela?

Answer (score 2):

Um banco de dados é composto por diversas tabelas, como por exemplo: Clientes, Produtos, Pedidos, Detalhes do Pedido, etc. Embora as informações estejam separadas em cada uma das Tabelas, na prática devem existir relacionamentos entre as tabelas. Por exemplo: Um Pedido é feito por um Cliente e neste Pedido podem existir diversos itens, itens que são gravados na tabela Detalhes do Pedido. Além disso cada Pedido possui um número único (Código do pedido), mas um mesmo Cliente pode fazer diversos pedidos e assim por diante.

Em um banco de dados, precisamos de alguma maneira para representar estes relacionamentos da vida Real, em termos das tabelas e de seus atributos. Isto é possível com a utilização de "Relacionamentos entre tabelas", os quais podem ser de três tipos:

- Um para Um
- Um para Vários
- Vários para Vários

**Relacionamento do Tipo Um para Um:**

Esta relação existe quando os campos que se relacionam são ambos do tipo Chave Primária, em suas respectivas tabelas. Cada um dos campos não apresenta valores repetidos. Na prática existem poucas situações onde utilizaremos um relacionamento deste tipo. Um exemplo poderia ser o seguinte: Imagine uma escola com um Cadastro de Alunos na tabela Alunos, destes apenas uma pequena parte participa da Banda da Escola. Por questões de projeto do Banco de Dados, podemos criar uma Segunda Tabela "Alunos da Banda", a qual se relaciona com a tabela Alunos através de um relacionamento do tipo Um para Um. Cada aluno somente é cadastrada uma vez na Tabela Alunos e uma única vez na tabela Alunos da Banda. Poderíamos utilizar o Campo Matrícula do Aluno como o Campo que relaciona as duas Tabelas.

Importante: O campo que relaciona duas tabelas deve fazer parte, ter sido definido, na estrutura das duas tabelas.

Na tabela Alunos da Banda poderíamos colocar apenas o Número da Matrícula do aluno, além das informações a respeito do Instrumento que ele toca, tempo de banda, etc. Quando fosse necessário buscar as informações tais como nome, endereço, etc, estas podem ser recuperadas através do relacionamento existente entre as duas tabelas, evitando, com isso, que a mesma informação (Nome, Endereço, etc) tenha que ser duplicada nas duas tabelas, inclusive aumentando a probabilidade de erros de digitação.

**Relacionamento do Tipo Um para Vários:**

Este é, com certeza, o tipo de relacionamento mais comum entre duas tabelas. Uma das tabelas (o lado um do relacionamento) possui um campo que é a Chave Primária e a outra tabela (o lado vários) se relaciona através de um campo cujos valores relacionados podem se repetir várias vezes.

Considere o exemplo entre a tabela Clientes e Pedidos. Cada Cliente somente é cadastrado uma única vez na tabela de Clientes (por isso o campo Código do Cliente, na tabela Clientes, é uma chave primária, indicando que não podem ser cadastrados dois clientes com o mesmo código), portanto a tabela Clientes será o lado um do relacionamento. Ao mesmo tempo cada cliente pode fazer diversos pedidos, por isso que o mesmo Código de Cliente poderá aparecer várias vezes na tabela Pedidos: tantas vezes quantos forem os pedidos que o Cliente tiver feito. Por isso que temos um relacionamento do tipo Um para Vários entre a tabela Clientes e Pedidos, através do campo Código do Cliente, indicando que um mesmo Cliente pode realizar diversos (vários) pedidos.

**Relacionamento do tipo Vários para Vários:**

Este tipo de relacionamento "aconteceria" em uma situação onde em ambos os lados do relacionamento os valores poderiam se repetir. Vamos considerar o caso entre Produtos e Pedidos. Posso ter Vários Pedidos nos quais aparece um determinado produto, além disso vários Produtos podem aparecer no mesmo Pedido. Esta é uma situação em que temos um Relacionamento do Tipo Vários para Vários.

Na prática não é possível implementar um relacionamento deste tipo, devido a uma série de problemas que seriam introduzidos no modelo do banco de dados. Por exemplo, na tabela Pedidos teríamos que repetir o Número do Pedido, Nome do Cliente, Nome do Funcionário, Data do Pedido, etc para cada item do Pedido.

[Aqui um bom PDF para você usar alguns exemplos!](http://www.uel.br/pessoal/valerio/08%20Criar%20relacionamento%20no%20access%20-%201%20folha.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se ajuda muito, mas a situação que você descreveu, em ambiente de banco de dados real (`Postgre`) por exemplo, eu faria uma `trigger` (gatilho), `after insert or update` na tabela `tbPessoas` e nessa `trigger` criaria uma função especifica para este campo (`IF old.campo <> new.campo`) faria um update buscando o curso relacionado.

No Access, eu não sei se tem como criar "trigger/gatilhos", mas pesquisa por isso, se tiver como acredito que uma trigger resolve seu problema. Exemplo de trigger no postgre: [Exemplo Trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 0):

Voce não deve fazer isso. Se fosse uma base NoSQL, até faria sentido, mas em um banco relacional, certamente está fazendo algo errado.

Se quer a lista de pessoas e quais cursos estão aplicando, use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tbPessoas P
  JOIN tbCurso C ON C.ID = P.CursoID
```

Isso vai resultar em uma consulta da maneira que espera.

E remova a coluna `CursoNome` da tabela tbPessoa, isso é redundancia de dados, portanto, má pratica. Ah, e também remove o `tb` no prefixo do nome das tablelas. Não é necessário e também é outra má prática.